# how to PUT multiple query parameter in REST web service

Tags: web-services, rest, curl, jax-rs, query-string

Do anyone know how to PUT multiple query parameter in REST web service?
I have write using java.My curl sample is like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/directory/sub-directory?name=shareuser&type=Read -v
```

My program is :

```
@PUT
@Path("{user}/{directory:.+}")
public Response doshare(@PathParam("user")String name,
        @PathParam("directory")String dir,
        @QueryParam("name")String sharename,
        @QueryParam("type")String type){
    mongoDAOImpl impl=new mongoDAOImpl();
    Mongo mongo=impl.getConnection("127.0.0.1","27017");
    DB db=impl.getDataBase(mongo,"public");
    DBCollection coll=impl.getColl(db,name);
    DBCollection coll2=impl.getColl(db,"sharedb");
    shareDTO sharedto=new shareDTO();
    String authority=type.toLowerCase();
    if(authority.equals("rd")){
        sharedto.setAuthority("4");
    }else if(authority.equals("rw")){
        sharedto.setAuthority("12");
    }
    sharedto.setTargetuser(sharename);
    sharedto.setRealURI("/home/public/"+name+"/"+dir);
    sharedto.setIdentifier(name);
    sharedto.setParentURI("/home/public/"+sharename);
    boolean bool = false;
    sharefun=new sharefunction();
    if(sharefun.checksubfoldershared(coll, coll2, sharedto)){
        bool=sharefun.sharefiles(coll, coll2, sharedto);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    // ...
```

But I only get the name query parameter.How to get or how to type in curl command in order to get all query parameter?

Comment: PUT and query params? That doesn't feel nice.

Comment: Any suggestion to fix it out? I am writing web service for window base application. I aldy have web application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code is fine - the problem is with the way you're invoking curl. When passing a URL to curl that contains a '&', you have to put quotes around the URL. Otherwise, the shell will interpret the stuff after the '&' as a separate command.

EDIT: My text is getting munged when I submit it as a comment. Here's what you need to do:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/directory/sub-directory?name=shareuser&type=Read' -v
```

Comment: i have invoked curl using "   curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/directory/sub-directory?name=shareuser'&'type=read   ". But I got exception Http "500". Still have a problem.  If I type is read&write , how shall i do? like " ?name=shareuser'&'type=read&write  "

Comment: No, read what I wrote again. Put quotes *around the URL*. Like this: curl 'http://example.com/?a=A&b=B'

Comment: hi mike, got same error Http 500. i wrote like : curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:8080?a=A&b=B'

Comment: A 500 error is something completely different than the problem you originally reported, so you might want to start another question. Also, a 500 just means that something went wrong during request processing, so it could be anything. There should be messages in the server log when the error happens - take a look at those first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the -d option? e.g.

```
curl -X PUT -d "name=shareuser&type=Read" http://locahost:8080/project/resources/user/directory/sub-directory -v
```

Comment: yes I have tried, but got same Error. Maybe Coz my PUT function is conflict. I have PUT function for create container also.

Answer (score 1):

You could try handling this all as a multipart upload (the server-side details aren't standardized and you didn't say what framework you're using so I can't give more clues) but I question why you're having the user and permissions set (via *any* parameters) in the first place. Surely you'd be better off deriving the user to store as through inspecting the user's login credentials and using a default set of permissions that they can change later on? Nearly as cheap, and *enormously* simpler.

Comment: hi donal, I don't use any framework for web service. I just create in NetBean as web application and write REST web service in POJO class. This PUT method is for share function not user athentication or upload. I am new to web service and I am doing interning about storage. Supervisor ask me to finish as early as possible. So colud u give any suggestion?

Comment: @user: You _bet_ you are using a framework! Something is processing those annotations to turn them into code that hooks everything together. Given that you're using Netbeans, I'd guess you're probably using Jersey even if you don't know it. Multipart handling in Jersey is an extension (jersey-multipart).