# Stash - Add user permission to Stash using REST API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to add a few users and also set their permissions with a provided JSON, but it's not working.
This command is working fine, but i want to add multiple users with JSON:

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT "http://stash.mydomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/CPC/permissions/users?name=myuser&permission=PROJECT_WRITE"
```

This command not working :

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT "http://stash.mydomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/CPC/permissions/users" -d '{"name" : "myuser", "permission" : "PROJECT_READ"}'
```

I'm getting an error: `{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Permission must be specified.","exceptionName":null}]}`

Any idea how to solve it? 
I need to add multiple users at once, this could be done using an Array inside a JSON.

Answer (score 5):

You can add muliple users by inserting the name paramter multiple times like

`curl -u admin:admin -X PUT "http://stash.mydomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/CPC/permissions/users?name=myuser&name=myuser2&permission=PROJECT_WRITE"`

The quotes around the URL are important. Without, you will get the error message again. See [how to PUT multiple query parameter in REST web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785610/how-to-put-multiple-query-parameter-in-rest-web-service)

Comment: This works great. How to add, say - name=myuser3&permission=PROJECT_READ?


"http://stash.mydomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/CPC/permissions/users?name=myuser&name=myuser2&permission=PROJECT_WRITE&name=myuser3&permission=PROJECT_READ"

I tried the above, works but gives the permission of PROJECT_WRITE to myuser3 instead of PROJECT_READ